# How to type in the Windows Ubuntu terminal while a windows exe is processing?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Typically in most terminals I've worked with (for instance, powershell or OSX's built-in "terminal") if you start typing your next command while the previous is still running, the terminal will receive your keyboard inputs and insert them anyway.

With the windows ubuntu terminal, all my keystrokes while the current command is running are lost.

This seems to only happen when I run a windows exe through the ubuntu terminal.

For example, this suppresses all my keyboard input: "ping.exe windows.com", while using ubuntu's ping does not: "ping windows.com"

Is there a fix to make it so that my keyboard input is not suppressed when running windows tools in the ubuntu terminal? I find this valuable since I often being typing the next command while the previous is still running.

Comment: Can you list some other windows executables that are blocking your input? I believe this may be a problem of `ping.exe` and not all executables. I am still able to type into Ubuntu while using `notepad.exe` for example.

Comment: This also reproduces with ripgrep (rg.exe), though that one is not a windows built-in.